# What's the meaning of the phrase "to name others"?

Tags: meaning, phrases

> By using this behavior, you can change
>   some of the default settings for this
>   provider like the connection string or
>   whether the instance should be removed
>   from the database after its
>   completion, **to name others**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means: To mention other settings

see -verb here: http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/name

You can also say, *to name a few*.  In this case, that would sound better if there are many more settings. Alternative: *to name some examples*

Answer (score 0):

You found a rare use of the phrase.  Be aware that **to name others** or **to name names** when applied to someone "giving out names of other people" has the very heavy meaning of ratting on others, by name, and thus pointing authorities to individuals who may be guilty of crimes. People name others to escape their own punishment for related crimes.